# What is the name for user-defined methods / functions that get called implicitly?

Tags: terminology, event-programming, inversion-of-control

I want to mark such methods in my application code with a comment that highlights that these methods are expected to get called by the framework / compiler the application is written for, even if the application code itself contains no calls to them.

F.ex. the methods called by an Inversion of Control framework, like the `beginRender` and `afterRender`  of [Apache Tapestry](http://tapestry.apache.org/); or the ones of an event-driven language, like the `Form_Load` of Visual Basic.

I was tempted to say *Event handlers* but I'm not sure it's correct to limit the concept to events; f.ex. in Tapestry a page rendering triggered by one event (like the click on a link) is composed of several phases and each phase has its own methods, and they get called by the framework; these phases occur in a predefined sequence, so it might be misleading for the reader of my comment if I call "event" each of them.

Sometimes *Callback* is suggested but I have the doubt that that only applies to a function that gets passed to other functions as an argument.

The only thing the functions / methods I'm talking about have in common is that they get called by the framework / compiler, regardless of whether the developer also codes explicit calls to it or not.

Comment: Emacs developers would never even dream of calling this anything else than a **hook**. The usage extends to other programs from the 1970s and 80s, although not quite so pervasively.

Comment: @KilianFoth _Hook_ sounds good, it's unfortunate that it's not so common but so far this is my best option, thanks. If I go for it I would ask you to make it an answer.

Comment: @KillianFoth unfortunately, "hook" also commonly means a function which intercepts an API call or event before it reaches its typical destination, e.g. in the Windows API functions SetWindowsHookEx and similar, so I wouldn't use it on this context these days.

Comment: @Jules Nice point, so _hook_ is not it either.

Comment: I'm not clear why this is considered opinion-based. If I ask "_what's the name for variables that only exist within the function where they are declared ?_", I wouldn't consider that as opinion-based and a valid answer would be "_local variables_". I fail to see the difference with my question. Of course another possible answer could always be "there is not a term to describe exactly that" (which is why I'll probably accept @Frank's answer), but IMO still not opinion-based. However I just edited it replacing the vague _automatically_ with an explanation, in case that was the issue.

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6582/on-the-troubles-of-naming-and-terminology

Comment: Re the accepted answer in @gnat's link above, to me this question totally falls into the category "`1. What is the name of this well-known concept?`". I don't understand how the type of methods I described is not a well-known concept. Just for the record though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others already pointed out, we do not normally assign an overarching name to these functions. I have heard all of these terms and seen them in action, but so far, no common name that crossed language/platform/framework boundaries seems to have emerged as far as I can tell. But I think it's a fine question nevertheless. As it was said, naming things is hard, but we all agree that it is also important, so here's my take on this:

**Hooks** are as @Kilian Foth pointed out quite the old-school term and indeed, I haven't heard that term in a long time. There's not really a reason why it went out of fashion as it is still valid, though I have to admit I never really liked the idea of a visual hook for this sort of concept.

**Handlers** have been named too, however, these do in general have a slightly different semantics in most of the cases I encountered them. Handlers are typically found in correspondence to user interactions (action / button handlers). **Event handlers** are a slightly more targeted term, which directly corresponds to events. Due to many domains explicictly modelling events, however, I also don't like that as a general term, since it can be confusing to have "event handlers" in the hook/callback sense, when there is no actual "event" involved.

**Callbacks** are close to hooks, but due to the term have a different directional emphasis. With a hook there is something existing and from the outside you hook into that, whereas a callback is something you pass along and at some time lateron, the other side will reach out to your callback. Other than that, callbacks have fallen out of fashion similarly to hooks with derogatory derived terms like "callback hell" coming to mind.

**"Implicitly"** is yet another term that already exists for such a case, yet has again a completely different semantics. Check out the Scala language, which offers "implicitly" as a direct language term even. Its meaning though is not that of a hook/callback/whatever we discuss here.

In addition to that, several frameworks do not even bother with names for this purpose. A typical case is the usage of f.ex. Java's **reflection** API. Consider the Beans standard, in which you have **accessor methods** (a.k.a. getters). Several frameworks call these methods automatically via reflection and they serve yet another purpose in contrast to all of the above.

As a **consequence** of this discussion, I would like to argue Obi-Wan-style, that *this term is not what you're looking for*. As we have seen, the different candidate terms have wildly differing semantics or reasons for being called automatically. It is even disputable what "automatic" means. Since naming is primarily a means to transport meaning, the very use of a term denoting  "automatically used function" is questionable.

As soon as you fix some of these variable semantical interpretation options (or if you prefer UML "semantic variation points") though, a term to identify your choices starts to make sense. That's why we do have hooks, event handlers, callbacks, implicit methods, property accessors and what-not. But each of these terms contains more information than the mere fact of "automatic calling", whatever that may be.

Comment: Urgh... I might end up just writing "Called automatically by Tapestry" then. However, given that for now I'm hooked on _hook_, what extra information  do you think one might receive from _hook_ besides "called automatically" ? I would like to avoid any potential extra meaning. As a side note, good point about _hook_ and _callback_ going out of fashion for no apparent good reason, it's probably just because they were around since long time and new generations like to come up with new terms.

Comment: As I point out in the comments to the question, "hook" is used in Microsoft documentation and API names with a slightly different meaning, which could be confusing.

Comment: I accept this answer now because I'm not sure I can still do that if the question gets closed, and it really seems that there is no conventional name for these functions, just like this answer suggests. It also contains very informative points.

Answer (score 1):

They're just … functions. Functions that the rest of the code you've written is already using.

If you're writing an application, then these are already indistinguishable from functions that code you might write in the future will be using.

If you're writing a library, making them `private` (and optionally providing a `public` wrapper) is a good way to isolate "functions I'm providing to the library user" from "functions my library uses itself". I then like to call them "internal functions" but that's probably just me.

I will note, however, that the specific examples you've given in your question all happen to be handlers/callbacks/hooks, so if you're not actually hoping for a broader term, that'll do just fine.

Naming things is hard. Sometimes we describe a function based on how we're using it in that context. Sometimes we describe a function based on how it is typically used. Sometimes we describe a function based on how it should always be used. Coming up with a general rule to cover all of these things, without context, is close to pointless. Just make your documentation clear and unambiguous, using as many English words as you need, and you'll be fine.

Comment: The functions I'm talking about, only the framework calls them, not my code; so I guess it's a matter of what we mean by code "using" a function, however the expression I need is exactly aimed at pointing out that difference. _Handler_ alone doesn't convey the "called automatically" meaning enough for me (probably due to the widespread practice of naming "FooHandler/Manager/Helper" anything that has to do with Foo). _Callback_ might have the problem I mentioned in the question, I don't know yet. _Hook_ is good. BTW the only thing I need to cover is that they get called automatically.

Comment: @SantiBailors: I think you're overusing/misusing the term "automatically", and that's causing your terminology problem. Every single function in your computer gets called automatically. Computers are automatic. That is their purpose. You're trying to make a distinction where there is none, or, at the very least, making a distinction and giving it the wrong name for the wrong reasons.

Comment: Agreed, computers are automatic and that's their purpose; but the distinction I make is definitely there. However it's true that I might be misusing the term "automatically", I can see that, it's actually overly generic and it doesn't even sound too professional. What expression might fit instead ? The distinction it should represent is between application methods that there is no reason to expect that the framework will call, and application methods that the framework is expected to call. Or I should probably just call them "framework-called methods".

Comment: @Santi I can't tell you what unambiguous expression to substitute for an ambiguous one, because it's ambiguous, which means I can't know what you mean by it ;) Although at a guess you seem to be triggering the third paragraph of my answer. They're internal functions. They're part of the internals of your library/framework/application and are not for "public consumption". Make them `private` or hide them in a `detail` namespace to enforce.

Comment: I'm unable to see how can that distinction be ambiguous, so I don't think any further effort of yours at explaining me can be fruitful, but I appreciated your points. About your last hint, I cannot make those "framework-called" methods `private` because the framework (Tapestry) wouldn't be able to call them any longer, and for the same reason I cannot alter their name because the name is what allows the framework to know they're there. There would be the same problem for the other example in my question (VB's `Form_Load`), while I realized that the Javascript one was wrong so I'm removing it.

Comment: @SantiBailors: Then take my other suggestion and emplace them in a `detail` namespace. That's common practice.